# Regex to replace all digits inside the varchar()

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hi All I am using notepad++ and I would like to have a regex expression that would detect only the numbers inside the varchar() only then replace all matches to 100

I have this regex expression but shows all the digits
(?:\d*.)?\d+

I'm new to regex please advise.
Thanks for your help!

```
    POLICYNO char(15) NULL, GDS_CODE char(8) NULL, ISSUE_DT datetime NULL, LAST_NM varchar(50) NULL, MI_NM varchar(50) NULL, FIRST_NM varchar(50) NULL,
BIRTH_DT datetime NULL, PASSPORT varchar(50) NULL, ADDLINE1 varchar(150) NULL, ADDLINE2 varchar(150) NULL, LOCALITY varchar(150) NULL, STATE varchar(90) NULL,
CITY varchar(90) NULL, STREET varchar(5) NULL, ZIP varchar(15) NULL, TEL varchar(30), MOBILE varchar(30), EMAIL varchar(120) NULL, DEPARTURE_DATE datetime NULL,
RETURN_DATE datetime NULL, PRODUCT_CD char(15) NULL, LOCATION_CD varchar(50) NULL, SECTION_CD char(15) NULL, RISK_CD varchar(5) NULL, INSURED_COV varchar(5) NULL
```

Comment: I'm just using notepad++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `varchar` contain floating point numbers.

Find what?

```
\bvarchar\(\d+\)
```

or

```
\bvarchar\s*\(\d+\)
```

Replace with:

```
varchar\(100\)
```

Comment: Thanks works for me. I just have an additional question, what if I wanted to change all varchar OR unichar to varchar(100)? Thanks!